# Tensorflow image sequence to sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to build [lrcn](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4389v4.pdf) in tensorflow, which is basically a seq2seq model in image. Just like typical language model except that image have to be transformed to image_embedding  through CNN.

The problem is that when I read sequence of image tensor of shape [seq_length, batch, w, h, c], I want to encode each tensor with my encoder(ex. AlexNet). (I unpack this tensor to get list of tensors of size seq_length)

I try to use tf.while_loop to iterate list of tensor but it seems that gradient computation does not work if using slicing inside a tf.while_loop. There are some discussion [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3114).

Is there a way to loop over list of tensors and encoded each tensor([b, w, h ,c]) with learnable network ? I tried several ways but the gradient computation seemed to be wrong. I think there must be a simple way to doing this, but I am just new to Tensorflow, any help or example will be appreciated.

the while loop approach I tried:

```
  input_array = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
            dtype=tf.float32, size=sequence_length,
            dynamic_size=False, infer_shape=True)
  encoded_array = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
            dtype=tf.float32, size=sequence_length,
            dynamic_size=False, infer_shape=True)
  decoded_array = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
            dtype=tf.float32, size=sequence_length,
            dynamic_size=False, infer_shape=True)

  input_array = input_array.unpack(inputT)

  def encoder_body(index, inputs, outputs):
    x = inputs.read(index)
    outputs = outputs.write(index, encoder(x, phase_train))
    return index + 1, inputs, outputs

  def decoder_body(index, inputs, outputs):
    x = inputs.read(index)
    outputs = outputs.write(index, decoder(x, phase_train, batch_size))
    return index + 1, inputs, outputs

  _, _, encoded_array = tf.while_loop(lambda i, j, k: i<sequence_length,
                                        encoder_body, (tf.constant(0), input_array, encoded_array))
  _, _, decoded_array = tf.while_loop(lambda i, j, k: i<sequence_length,
                                        decoder_body, (tf.constant(0), encoded_array, decoded_array))
```

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this question?